# Pandoc revealjs footnotes on same slide instead of end of the document

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I am converting markdown to HTML slides using pandoc and revealjs. Whenever I put footnotes, all of them appear at the last slide.

What I instead want is to put my footnotes on the same slide where it is referenced. Is it possible to do so?